# window.open() tracking user input

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to see (for anyone but google.com - website owner, server owner etc) which input was inserted into form, and which link was generated?

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="id_1" size="20" placeholder="user input">        
  <input type="submit" value="GO" 
    onclick="window.open('https://google.com/'+ 
    document.getElementById('id_1').value); return false;">             
</form>
```

Would it be possible for anyone (other than google.com) to see which input was made by user, or which link the user opened?

Comment: Yes, the user would. And anyone looking at their browser history or network activity. The more interesting question is, why are you asking the question?

Comment: Are you asking if a third party can track google searches? Because that depends on a lot of factors that aren't specified in the question.

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. What problem are you trying to solve? (It sounds like one about privacy, but then you should be asking something like "How can I ensure that nobody except my user and my server can see data submitted in a form).

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: This is a matter of privacy I would say. There are a number of sites that contain these forms that send you further to Google or Facebook; I am wondering if by using these HTML forms with window.open() method, the website owners would be able to track user input, or where the user (that made the input and clicked the submit button) was sent to (which link was generated?